# Call a method in android - practical examples

Tags: java, android, xml, class, methods

I'm new to Android / Java. I want to modify a simple open source Android game. It's much easier for me to learn programming with real examples.

**Goal**: I want to generate random backgrounds when the game is going to the next level or when the player is starting a new game.

**Already:** I found a way to generate random backgrounds when the user is starting the application, replacing the following code:

```
  mBackgroundOrig =
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.background, options);
```

with:

```
      TypedArray imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.random_background);
      Random rand = new Random();
      int rndInt = rand.nextInt(imgs.length());
      int resID = imgs.getResourceId(rndInt, 0);
      mBackgroundOrig = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, randBackground.resID, options);
```

in: https://code.google.com/p/bubble-shoot/source/browse/trunk/bubble-shooter-pro/src/com/likeapp/game/bubbleshooter/GameView.java

And create a XML file with a string array in **values/rand_bkgnd.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="random_background">
        <item name="background_01">@drawable/background01</item>
        <item name="background_02">@drawable/background02</item>
        <item name="background_03">@drawable/background03</item>
        <item name="background_04">@drawable/background04</item>
        <item name="background_05">@drawable/background05</item>
        <item name="background_06">@drawable/background06</item>
        <item name="background_07">@drawable/background07</item>
        <item name="background_08">@drawable/background08</item>
        <item name="background_09">@drawable/background09</item>
        <item name="background_10">@drawable/background10</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

**Request:** Please help me to create a method with the above randomize background code. I'd like to have this code in a separate java file and to be able to call it from **goToNextLevel()** method when the player is finishing one level and is going to the next level:

```
public void goToNextLevel() {
    SharedPreferences sp =this.mContext.getSharedPreferences(
               BubbleShooterActivity.PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    currentLevel = sp.getInt(BubbleShooterActivity.PREFS_LEVEL_KEY_NAME, 0);
    int maxLevel = sp.getInt(BubbleShooterActivity.PREFS_UNLOCK_LEVEL_KEY_NAME, 0);     
    currentLevel++;
    if(maxLevel<=currentLevel){
        maxLevel=currentLevel;
    }
    sp.edit().putInt(BubbleShooterActivity.PREFS_LEVEL_KEY_NAME, currentLevel).putInt(BubbleShooterActivity.PREFS_UNLOCK_LEVEL_KEY_NAME, maxLevel).commit();
    if (currentLevel >= MAX_LEVEL_NUM) {
        currentLevel = 0;
    }
}
```

in: https://code.google.com/p/bubble-shoot/source/browse/trunk/bubble-shooter-pro/src/com/likeapp/game/bubbleshooter/LevelManager.java

I'm assuming this must be very easy for somebody with at least average Java skills. Please provide me examples based on my code / game and step by step instructions or explanation.

Comment: I just wonder, why I got a negative vote for my question without any kind of explanation ? So, should I consider that a bad joke of a pathetic member of this forum ? Or should I consider it the over reaction of a frustrated java / android programmer that doesn't understand the very simple freaking fact there are noobies out there in desperate need for help ?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a class(for example, Background.class)

```
package com.yourpackage.name;

public class Background{
    public <type of the image> RandomBackground(){
        TypedArray imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.random_background);
        Random rand = new Random();
        int rndInt = rand.nextInt(imgs.length());
        int resID = imgs.getResourceId(rndInt, 0);
        mBackgroundOrig = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, randBackground.resID, options);
        return mBackgroundOrig;
    }
}
```

and in your goToNextLevel() method

```
mBackgroundOrig = background.RandomBackground();//add this


public void goToNextLevel() {
mBackgroundOrig = background.RandomBackground(); //to this
SharedPreferences sp =this.mContext.getSharedPreferences(
           BubbleShooterActivity.PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
currentLevel = sp.getInt(BubbleShooterActivity.PREFS_LEVEL_KEY_NAME, 0);
int maxLevel = sp.getInt(BubbleShooterActivity.PREFS_UNLOCK_LEVEL_KEY_NAME, 0);     
currentLevel++;
if(maxLevel<=currentLevel){
    maxLevel=currentLevel;
}
sp.edit().putInt(BubbleShooterActivity.PREFS_LEVEL_KEY_NAME, currentLevel).putInt(BubbleShooterActivity.PREFS_UNLOCK_LEVEL_KEY_NAME, maxLevel).commit();
if (currentLevel >= MAX_LEVEL_NUM) {
    currentLevel = 0;
}
```

}

you also need to include the class in your main class for you to call the RandomBackground() Method.

for example:

```
Background background;
```

before the onCreate() Method